# Remove space from title & wrap second word with span tag in PHP

Tags: php, string

I'm trying to take an `<h2>` title (typically two words) and remove the spaces and wrap the second word in a span tag so I can change the color. Can this be done with a combo of PHP string functions?

```
$property_title = get_field('property_title'); 
$new_title = "PHP STRING FUNCTION"
echo $new_title;
```

Example of desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and [`preg_match_all`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and then rebuild the title from the matched elements.

```
$property_title = get_field('property_title'); 
// $property_title = '<h2>emerald bay</h2>'; 

// First find all of the words between <h1>, <h2>, <h3>, <h4>, <h5> or <h6> elements.
preg_match("/(<h[1-6][^>]*?>)([\\s\\S]*?)(<\/h[1-6]>)/i", $property_title, $initial_matches);

// Now match all of the words in the string. 
preg_match_all("/([a-zA-Z]+)/i", $initial_matches[2], $matches);

// Set the point where a <span> should be set.
// $span_point = 1;
$span_point = count($matches[0]) - 1;

// Roll through the matched words & apply some logic to the span being set.$new_title = '';
$new_title = $initial_matches[1];
foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $value) {
  $new_title .= $key == $span_point ? "<span>" . $value . "</span>" : $value; 
}
$new_title .= $initial_matches[3];

// Echo the final title.
echo $new_title;
```

I am pretty sure there is some way to combine the logic of `preg_match` and `preg_match_all` into one regex, but I am not 100% sure on how to do that so I split the logic into two distinct chunks. Also, I set the `$span_point` to be the last word in the text, but you can manually override it—like I have in my comments—to force one specific element to be wrapped.

Answer (score 0):

[explode()](http://php.net/explode) will help you.
so this will take a word chop it into an array take last element and wrap it into a span...

```
$words = "MORE THAN ONE WORD";
$wordsArray = explode(" ", $words);

$newWord = "";
foreach($wordsArray as $num => $word){
    if ($num == sizeof($wordsArray) - 1){
         $word = "<span>$word</span>";
    }
    $newWord .= $word;    
}
echo $newWord;
```